# My MacBook Pro WiFi gets Internet access only while lid close

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I think I modified something in my Mac Pro WiFi settings. WiFi gets Internet access only while lid is closed. If I type http://facebook.com, it shows nothing. If I then close the lid and open again, after a while it shows Facebook content.

I don't know what might be causing this problem.

Comment: A Mac Pro is a big desktop machine, and has no lid. Presumably you mean a MacBook Pro? If so, which year model?

Comment: Do you have any USB devices attached?

Comment: yes i attached for mouse

Comment: thank @benwiggy after i remove mouse usb it work.  but i like to use mouse also how can i handle it

Comment: Confirm this by plugging in a mouse, keyboard, and monitor and see if you can continue to browse while closed.